Python using visual studio print function not displaying the output
Task: Check if an integer is positive or negative.
Check if the integer is divisible by 2 or not.
When 0 is entered I need to exit the loop and report each of the counts and sums. No output is displayed from the print function.
This is the code I'm using starting from the def main()
def main():
count positive = 0
count negative = 0
count_divisible_by_2 = 0
sum positive = 0
sum negative = 0
sum_divisible_by_2 = 0
while True:
  try:
   number = integer(input("Enter a integer(or the number 0 to stop): "))
  except `Value Error`:
   print("Invalid integer. Please enter a valid number value. :")
   print ("Enter the correct integer")
   
   if number == 0:
        break
   if number > 0:
        count positive += 1
        sum positive += number
   else number < 0:
        count negative += 1
        sum negative += number
  if number % 2 == 0:`
        count_divisible_by_2 += 1
        sum_divisible_by_2 += number
             
print(f "Positive integers count: {count positive}, sum: {sum positive}")
print(f "Negative integers count: {count negative}, sum: {sum negative}")
print(f "Integers divisible by 2 count: {count_divisible_by_2}, sum: {sum_divisible_by_2}")``

The output expected is the positive count, negative count, and if the integer is divisible by 2.
Visual Studio Code

I would advise to reformat your code, Python uses spaces / tabs to separate each line and also to define scopes. Your code either wouldn't run or it has some indentation issues.

You shouldn't have backticks around Value Error, and it doesn't have a space. except ValueError:

You have lots of basic syntax problems. count positive += 1 and sum positive += number are not valid. You need to go back to the books and learn the language.

Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, but I suggest you to read some online tutorials to learn python's syntax properly. As it is currently written, it seems like you do not have any understanding of Python's syntax model. For example, backtick are always syntax errors in Python3, and variables names with spaces in-between are clearly syntax errors.

You had a bunch of errors in your code.
First, the try-catch block had logic executing in the exception part. It's best practice to just identify the error in the exception part and continue to execute code (or break if needed) and jump back to the try part. I've modified the code to do just that.
You had other syntax errors which I'm not going to go over. I'd suggest you use an IDE like VSCode that will "lint" (linting is a program that checks your code before you run it to identify syntax errors) your code. This will help you learn the syntax quicker as you can see exactly where you went wrong as you write your code. Other comments mentioned the backticks, but I'll excuse that as I believe you were trying to make a code block using markdown for StackOverflow (I hope).
When you printed out the strings, you had a space between the "f" character and the string quotes. "f" in this context stands for "format", and needs to be placed next to the string quotes in order for python to recognize it as a formatted string and insert the variables accordingly.
I updated the variable names to be more readable and use underscores instead of spaces as like other comments mentioned, the python interpreter is going to pick up spaces as new variables, thus throwing errors in your code. (you are declaring two variables that are unassigned when you put a space in what you intended to be one variable name).
That's about it. You can learn python syntax with Python's official tutorial, which I haven't run through myself (I learned the basics of programming through Java, so python is pretty self-explanatory to me), but I'm sure it is a great starting point, since I can tell you are a beginner: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html
P.S. I also added a main method so you can execute this program with python main.py assuming you named the program main.py (you can name it whatever just point python to that program name).
def main():
     positive_count = 0
     negative_count = 0
     divisible_count = 0
     positive_sum = 0
     negative_sum = 0
     divisible_sum = 0

     while True:
          try:
               number = int(input("Enter a integer(or the number 0 to stop): "))

               if number == 0:
                    break
               if number > 0:
                    positive_count += 1
                    positive_sum += number
               elif number < 0:
                    negative_count += 1
                    negative_sum += number
               if number % 2 == 0:
                    divisible_count += 1
                    divisible_sum += number
          except ValueError:
               print("Invalid integer. Please enter a valid number value.\n")
               continue

                    
     print(f"Positive integers count: {positive_count}, sum: {positive_sum}")
     print(f"Negative integers count: {negative_count}, sum: {negative_sum}")
     print(f"Integers divisible by 2 count: {divisible_count}, sum: {divisible_sum}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Thank you everyone. I see where my code was incorrect my while True statement code for if, elif and else should have been added to my def check positive and negative statement,  and def check divisible by 2. Also, my return statement was in consistence with the initial def statement.

Fixed code:
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter an integer (or the number 0 to stop): "))
        if number == 0:
            break
       positive_sum, positive_count, negative_sum, negative_count = 
check_positive_negative(
            number, positive_sum, positive_count, negative_sum, negative_count)
        divby2_count, not_divby2_count = check_divisible_by_2(
            number, divby2_count, not_divby2_count)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. Please enter a valid number value.\n")
        continue


I'm new stack overflow. My post above is a summary of the code fix I used. I was able to print the output of the loop created thank you all again.
